# Why does a U.S. credit card application ask for other citizenships?

Tags: united-states, credit-card, credit-score

Looking at a credit card application, they are asking U.S. citizens whether they are citizens of another country.

Why are they asking for this information?

Will it hurt the application to disclose this information?

What are the consequences of not disclosing this information?

What laws are pertinent (anti-laundering, etc.)?

If the person has multiple foreign citizenships, which one should they enter?

Comment: at a guess: anyone with another citizenship is a greater flight risk, since they have somewhere they can easily flee to.

Comment: Here's something that may help: http://ficoforums.myfico.com/t5/Credit-Cards/Credit-Card-Application-quot-Are-you-a-US-Citizen-quot/td-p/4726824